# Generic detail view must be called with either an object pk or a slug

Tags: django

I am receiving that error when I try to visit the detail page of my product model. I have the slug field in the url file, but it doesn't seem to matter.

Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name= models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="the product name")
    product_slug= models.SlugField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="the product slug")
    product_excerpt= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="product excerpt")
    def _set_product_code(self):
        product_code_temp = hashlib.sha224()
        product_hash = self.product_name
        product_hash = product_hash.encode('utf-8')
        product_code_temp.update(product_hash)
        return product_code_temp.hexdigest()[0:5]
product_code = property(_set_product_code)
```

View

```
class ProductPage(DetailView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product'
    template_name="product.html"
```

Url

```
url(r'^product/(?P<product_slug>\w+)/(?P<product_code>\w+)/$', ProductPage.as_view(), name="product"),
```

Can anyone pinpoint what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set the `slug_field` attribute on the view class:

```
class ProductPage(DetailView):
    model = Product
    slug_field = 'product_slug'
```

Depending on your URLConf you may also need to specify the name of the kwarg that corresponds to the slug. It defaults to 'slug'. If you used something different in the URL specification, such as 'product_slug' in this example, specify the `slug_url_kwarg` property on the view as well:

```
    slug_url_kwarg = 'product_slug'
    # etc
```

Answer (score 8):

I would like to add that [get_object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) could also be used in a case where we have a different look up parameter for primary key

Example, if I want to get my object by [guid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier), which I am passing in my URLConf

```
def get_object(self):
    return Product.objects.get(guid=self.kwargs.get("guid"))
```

Comment: this worked. get_object should be added in detailview. And a little typo, it is uuid and NOT guid

Answer (score 0):

**models.py**

```
product_slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, help_text="Product slug field", db_column="product_slug",
                                verbose_name="slug product", error_messages={"required": "Enter the slug field"},
                                unique=True, )
```

Use below regex to write in one line for pk and slug :

**urls.py**

```
url(r'(^products/(?P<pk>\d+)/$)|(^products/(?P<product_slug>\w+)/$)',ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail-view')
```

**views.py**

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
     model = Products
     extra_context = {'title': 'products-detail-view'}
     pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
     query_pk_and_slug = True
     slug_field = 'product_slug'
     slug_url_kwarg = 'product_slug'
```